# Avoid duplicate row in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have an object A in my dataBase that contains a collection C with 2rows.

when i use criteria Hibernate to get my object , i got the some object for each item on collection C . I used :

```
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SillonBD.class);
  criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

And

// not work because that retuen only id

```
 criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id")))
```

;

But that's not work for me hibernate does not return distinct results for my object  with outer join fetching enabled for a collection

Comment: can you share your classes and mentioned what is coming as duplicate? Also can you share the complete criteria query?

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id")));
```

Comment: that return just id in my object and i want all my object